# Help with the contradiction: 生産を条件付きで承認した and 州政府の認可を待っていた

Tags: comprehension

> 米テスラが近く欧州で初の生産を始めることがほぼ確実になった。独ブランデンブルク州は4日、ベルリン郊外グリューンハイデにテスラが建設している「ギガファクトリー」での生産を条件付きで承認した。この工場ではすでに試験生産を始めており、州政府の認可を待っていた。

I find the text a bit contradictory. The second sentence says the state conditionally approved the production but the third sentence says it is still waiting for the approval from the state government. So I'm confused. Do I have some misunderstanding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the third sentence says it is still waiting for the approval from the state government.

It says 州政府の認可を待ってい**た**。, not 州政府の認可を待ってい**る**。

> **すでに**試験生産を始め**ており**、州政府の認可を待っ**ていた**。
> It **had already started** pilot production and **had been** waiting for the approval (until the state approved the production on 4th.)